# african newpapers for the past 20 years for machine learning

Tags: data-request, web-crawling, machine-learning

I am starting a project looking at textual analysis (topic analysis and sentiment analysis) for newspapers African countries, including Gambia, Nigeria, and Tanzania. However, I was wondering if anyone knew of good repositories or archives of African newspapers or textual data (preferably in English). Newspapers would be great, but also blog posts or other resources. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good starting place (compiled by Columbia University):

**Nigeria:**

http://library.columbia.edu/locations/global/virtual-libraries/african_studies/countries/nigeria/online.html

**Tanzania:**

http://library.columbia.edu/locations/global/virtual-libraries/african_studies/countries/tanzania/online.html

Answer (score 1):

I've only just seen your query, Krishna, so am not certain whether you still need the info, but [Code for Africa](https://www.facebook.com/CodeForAfrica/) might be able to help for machine readable archives of newspaper content from Kenya, South Africa, Zambia, and a couple of other south east African countries. Shout if you need access.